# error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am getting this following error,

I have a "A.c" file in which I have included a "b.h" file, which has a "c.h" file. 
Now this c.h has structures which are getting used and they are all int. 
the structures are used in the following way:

In "c.h" file

```
struct abc{

int a;<---- error

};
```

In "b.h"

```
struct def{

struct abc;

};
```

and I have used `struct def` in file "A.c" file. 
Please, help me know what wrong have I done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some nesting error, a missing `;` or something that confuses the compiler.

I would recommend trying to get hold of the preprocessor output, so you can see what the compiler sees, once the `#includes` have been executed.

Comment: How do I take a preprocessor output??

Comment: If you are using gcc, use: `gcc -E file.c`